# In a buffer with widgets how can I find out what function is called on a (link) widget

Tags: help, widget

In a buffer with widgets how can I find out what functions widgets call?

Let's say I position the cursor on a widget, I execute `M-x widget-browse-at` and know now that the widget is of class "**link**".

From experiments I know that activating the widget (i.e. pressing `RET` on it) creates an new buffer, but what function calls it for this?

`describe-key` gives me only `wid-edit` as a function, but somehow `wid-edit` then must call the real action function.

**How can I find out which function that is?**

Is there something like an action table for widgets?

---

#### Some more details:

1) When I am on the widget and call `M-x widget-browse-at` I get a buffer like this:

```
Widget object browser.

Class: link

:args


:value
    "Open"

:notify
    [show]

:button-overlay
    #<overlay from 316 to 322 in *ein:notebooklist http://127.0.0.1:8989*>

:from
    [show]

:to
    #<marker at 322 in *ein:notebooklist http://127.0.0.1:8989*>
```

2) When in *that* buffer I am on the **[show]** widget of the `:notify` property and I call `M-x widget-browse-at` I get:

```
Widget object browser.

Class: push-button

:args


:value
    [show]

:tag
    "show"

:action
    [show]

:button-overlay
    #<overlay in no buffer>

:from
    [show]

:to
    #<marker in no buffer>
```

3) Using `M-x widget-browse-at` again doesn't give anything new.

So `M-x widget-browse-at` doesn't seem to point me to the function eventually called (which in this case probably is `ein:notebook-open`).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the widget library. It is not widely used except the customization buffer. I guess there should be a `:notify` field, its value is a function and will be called when you click the link. I find this by trying the "other work" link of [(widget) Programming Example](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/widget/Programming-Example.html).

Comment: @xuchunyang In my case (of the EIN notebook list) the `:notify` field just contains `[show]`...

Comment: You need to check `[show]` to show the function.

Comment: @xuchunyang looking with widget-browse-at at the **[show]** field doesn't reveal any function, just `:value` = **[show]** and `:action` = **[show]**. I'll put this in the question.

Comment: Look what `:action` of the `push-button` says. I.e., click on `[show]` there.

Comment: Note that the job of `:notify` is to notify the parent widgets in the hierarchy. That means the link is embedded into a push button. The actual action of the push button is the `:action` property of the widget. Sometimes the action is just to notify the parents.

Comment: @Tobias The original widget (of class **link**) doesn't have an action, the link widget (of class **push-button**) has `:notify` and `:action` properties but both have just a **[show]** value. I guess the parent is doing somehow all the work... I wish widgets would have a proper `describe-widget` command!

Comment: Did you `<mouse-2>` on `[show]`? It should show you the underlying setting.